# VBA Trying to make WorkSheet_Change work on multiple sheets but not all

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I need to make a Worksheet_Change that checks for the change of values in 2 different cells in 2 different sheets. However I have more than 2 sheets and don't want to use a Workbook_Change so those other sheets are not affected.

My Code works but only checks for the cells in one worksheet but not for the other worksheet. I need to check in both worksheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M9")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call Macro5
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I88")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call Macro6
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

  End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to place the code in the other worksheet module as well then

Comment: Wow I have been working with excel for a while and never realized I could put different code for different sheets. Thanks a lot for your help :).

Comment: There's also the Workbook-level `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` which you could use to avoid duplicating your code (and exit if `Sh.Name` is not one of your monitored sheets)

Comment: I tried to do that earlier but I could not figure out how to include the Sh in the declaration of the IF statement. What I mean is I didn't know what to add before the Target in "If Not Intersect(,Target, Range("M9")) Is Nothing Then" to allow me to differentiate among sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Workbook's code module you can access events triggered on any Worksheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
      Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If (Not Intersect(Target, Range("M9")) Is Nothing) Then
        Call Macro5
    ElseIf (Not Intersect(Target, Range("M9")) Is Nothing) Then
        Call Macro6
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you need to know what worksheet the event fired on you can use the ByVal Sh As Object parameter.

> If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" then

If you want to access the Sh object's properties using intellisense, cast Sh back from a Object back into a WorkSheet Object

```
Dim ws as WorkSheet
Set ws = Sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The Private command restricts your subroutine to the current worksheet, so you're correct in using that command to keep the subroutine from altering all of your sheets.

Like newguy said, the simplest fix is to place the code in each of the worksheet modules you want it to alter, each using the Private command.